# jaxb: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"head") - bit there is no "head" element

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I am getting an "unexpected element" error when working with the [NIST CPE](https://nvd.nist.gov/cpe.cfm) using it's standard [CPE 2.3 XML Schema Definition](http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cpe/2.3/cpe-dictionary_2.3.xsd).

JAXBException with this error is returned:

```
unexpected element (uri:"", local:"head"). Expected elements are <{http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0}cpe-item>,<{http://cpe.mitre.org/dictionary/2.0}cpe-list>
```

- My question is: **what does this error mean?**
- and are there any tips for fixing it?

Notes:

- I created the JAXB through Eclipse Neon using right-click > generate with only strict validation ticked
- There is no element called "head" (or "Head") in the XSD, JaxB or XML
- the JAXB generation did not create any @XmlDocumentRoot annotations for the CPE XSD - I think because the CPE XSD uses xpath.

Unmarshalling Code is pretty straightforward:

```
        URL url = new URL("http://static.nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cpe/dictionary/official-cpe-dictionary_v2.3.xml");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        InputStream plainXMLCPE = connection.getInputStream();

        JAXBContext jaxbContext  = JAXBContext.newInstance(ListType.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();           
        JAXBElement<ListType> cpeList = (JAXBElement<ListType>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(plainXMLCPE);
        ListType thelist = cpeList.getValue();
```

Unlike similar questions; I don't think this is an upper/lowercase issue with an element name because the element name "head" simply doesn't appear anywhere.  I don't fully understand why the uri is marked as "" in the error message.

I have tried to manually add @XmlRootElement annotations to the JaxB created classes to no effect. It automatically created a package-info.java that has the right namespace.

Comment: SOLVED.  It's a bit embarrassing but the XML link given on the NIST website responds with an HTTP code and a "document moved" html page that does not have <html> tags but starts with <head>.  I didn't see this when browsing with a browser -- lesson is always check the http return codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there are two questions here:

1. Where is this `<head>` element coming from?   and
2. Why isn't JAXB catching this error earlier?

The answer to 1. is that you probably saved the XSD incorrectly, from a browser, causing the extra HTML `<head/>` tag to get written into what you thought you were saying as your XSD file.

In Firefox, for example, when you do *File->Save Page As* you would go down to the drop-down "Save as Type" and select **Web Page, XML Only** (which will save without the extra HTML) rather than **Web Page Complete** (which is akin to what you must have done).

If you open the XSD you thought you were saving and look carefully you'll see a  tag in your local copy.

So that's easily fixed.  I know IE has a similar option and haven't checked Chrome lately.

---

As for 2., though, I'm not sure how you got through JAXB generation successfully.  I just tried to recreate it a couple times (using EclipseLink MOXy) but I can't get that far with the `<head/>` tag in there.

If you answer how you've configured JAXB from Eclipse and I can help I'll try to update my answer.

Comment: The file is being downloaded directly from source using url.openConnection() and I have tried using connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml"); which you would think would prevent html elements from being included...

Comment: Hmm...maybe that (a mistake I've made myself) didn't help so much then.  If you paste the code you're using to download the top-level and imported XSDs, I'll run it and let you know if I see anything.

Comment: the code in the question should be runnable.  All you download the linked XSD from NIST CPE page (linked) and create the JAXB.  I used standard Eclipse Neon JaxB capability (right click on the XSD (imported into eclipse project) -> generate -> JaxB) using standard config with strict validation.

Comment: you nailed it.  I directed the input stream to a file to have a look and there was a "Document Moved" web page with a <head> section.